# Trouble working with 3 ax objects on the same subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
%matplotlib inline

avg_discount = pd.read_json('{"Date":{"0":1498694400000,"1":1498780800000,"2":1498867200000,"3":1498953600000,"4":1499040000000},"Discount":{"0":0.2136567047,"1":0.2186422586,"2":0.2171303955,"3":0.2273395644,"4":0.2285249182}}')
auth_counts = pd.read_json('{"index":{"0":"False","1":"True"},"authorized":{"0":155,"1":22}}')
violation_counts = pd.read_json('{"index":{"0":"False","1":"True"},"violations":{"0":55,"1":7}}')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label='1')
ax2 = ax1.twinx() #tried .twiny() but didn't work as desired
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label='2', frame_on=False)
bar_positions = arange(2) + 0.75
ax1.bar(bar_positions, auth_counts['authorized'],0.5, color='#b0c4de')
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
tick_positions = range(1,3)
ax1.set_xticks(tick_positions)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['Unauthorized','Authorized'])
ax2.bar(bar_positions, [55,7], 0.5)
ax2.set_ylim([1,160])
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', top='off', right='off', labelright='off')
ax3.plot(avg_discount['Date'], avg_discount['Discount'], color='r', marker='o')
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off',labelleft='off')
ax3.set_xticklabels([val.day for val in avg_discount['Date']], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Data Explained:
- ax1 represents two different groups and their counts. ax2 represents of those two groups who has performed a certain action. ax3 adds a trend line of a statistic that defines the action taken by the members of these groups.

The Problem:
- The x axis and the correlated data points are not lined up for the line plot, ax3. Also, I'd like to neatly show the date, but settled for showing the day. Any suggestions on how to better represent this data would be appreciated.
- While I managed to get both bar charts to overlap, they are no longer neatly spaced out. I can only assume this is because matplotlib is trying to find an xlimit that satisfies all 3 charts, but when I edit the xlimit for all 3 to 10, ax3 says the limit is out of range.

Expected output:
- The output I'm looking for should look somewhat similar to the output of just the first bar chart. With the 2nd barchart overlaying on the 1st and the line plotted across the figure.

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: "neatly <some verb> <some object>" is not a proper problem description. After reading the question twice, I still don't know what the problem is. Can you describe exactly what is wrong with the plot and how it should look instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've edited my question. From my understanding, setting the x ticks at .75 and 1.5 with a width of .5 would result with the first bar starting at .75 on the x axis and ending at 1.25 and the 2nd starting at 1.5 and ending at 2. I'd like to maintain margins on each side.

Comment: Trying to run your code gives an error. Can you provide a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the bar positions to some integer number, e.g. `0` and `1`, which makes it easier to handle the spacings. If the bar is center-aligned `align="center"` and has a width of 0.8, it extents from -0.4 to 0.4, or from 0.6 to 1.4. Setting the xlim to `[-1,2]` leaves enough space around the bars. Of course you may chose other values to your liking.

To format the date axes, you may use matplotlib dates locators and formatters (also see [the dates example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)).

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
#%matplotlib inline

avg_discount = pd.read_json('{"Date":{"0":1498694400000,"1":1498780800000,"2":1498867200000,"3":1498953600000,"4":1499040000000},"Discount":{"0":0.2136567047,"1":0.2186422586,"2":0.2171303955,"3":0.2273395644,"4":0.2285249182}}')
auth_counts = pd.read_json('{"index":{"0":"False","1":"True"},"authorized":{"0":155,"1":22}}')
violation_counts = pd.read_json('{"index":{"0":"False","1":"True"},"violations":{"0":55,"1":7}}')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label='1')
ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label='2', frame_on=False)

bar_positions = arange(2)
ax1.bar(bar_positions, auth_counts['authorized'],0.8, color='#b0c4de', align="center")
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
tick_positions = range(1,3)
ax1.set_xticks(bar_positions)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['Unauthorized','Authorized'])
ax2.bar(bar_positions, [55,7], 0.8, align="center")
ax2.set_ylim([1,160])
ax2.set_xlim([-1,2]) # set xlim manually, if wanted

ax2.tick_params(axis='both', top='off', right='off', labelright='off')
ax3.plot(avg_discount['Date'], avg_discount['Discount'], color='r', marker='o')
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off',labelleft='off')
plt.setp(ax3.get_xticklabels(), rotation=60, ha="right")
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator())
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))

plt.show()
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code exactly and got the result which i've added to my original question. My line plot starts at my xlimit without giving the buffer shown in the image you posted. Regardless of what i switch the xlimit to, it always starts at the beginning and stretches all the way across the x axis.

Comment: So do you want to have this margin for the line plot or not?

Comment: The image you posted is the spitting image of what I want mine to look like, but I can't get mine to look like that picture even with playing with the xlim.

Comment: Ok, since you probably have an older version of matplotlib, you would need to add `ax3.margins(x=0.05)`. This adds 5% margin to both ends on the x axis.